# CSS Grid with multiple scroll areas in different directions

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to build a rather complex grid using HTML and CSS. It looks something like this:

[image]

- The left column does not scroll horizontally
- The other columns scroll horizontally (4 columns are shown, there could be 100 columns hidden by scroll overflow)
- The yellow/red headers do not scroll vertically
- The gray rows scroll vertically (5 rows are shown, there could be a 100 rows hidden by scroll overflow), in 2 independent sections (ie the the red header row divides two independent vertical scroll lists)
- The entire grid is a fixed width/height

It seems no matter how I slice up the grid something doesn't scroll as expected:

- If I put the left column in a `<div>` and the right columns in a `<div>` I can achieve the desired horizontal scrolling of just the right columns, but vertical scrolling is not synced between the left and right, and the presence of the scrollbar in the right columns misaligns with the grid rows between the left and right.
- If I put the gray rows in a `<div>` and the red/yellow headers in a `<div>` then the vertical scroll of the gray rows works as desired, but the horizontal scrolling doesn't scroll the headers and the rows together, and the left column just scrolls horizontally with the rows instead of staying fixed.

In some cases I was able to sync scrolling using JavaScript, but it was very badly delayed when using the mousewheel and looked pretty terrible.

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

If we remove the lower half of the list (so there is only one area of vertically scrolling rows) is it achievable with only CSS?

Comment: Hi **Aaron**, 
Are you want only use css not js or jquery? We can achieve by jQuery.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/) what you want?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam Yes, it can be done with JS, but I ran into problems with lag and performance problems, my real data-set is quite complex.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Thanks, yes that is pretty much what I currently have (using JS to sync scrolling offset). Maybe it's the only way.

Comment: @AaronBeall did you find a solution? I search the same solution too. ;-)

Comment: @FrédéricMascaro I never found a pure CSS way to do it.